# Error with constraint ... foreign key in Prod and Test environments. Dev works well. - Grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-plugin, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class

I have a system in Grails 2.5.3 and I have problems with the *Bootstrap* file in test and production environments. In **DEV environment the initial data load works perfectly.**

Domain class used. **SecUser** - Spring security

```
class SecUser implements Serializable {

    ...
    UUID id
    Date dateCreated
    String username
    String password
    String email
    ....
}
```

Normal user. **User**:

```
class User extends SecUser {

    UUID id
    String name
    ...

    // Relations
    static belongsTo = [department:Department]
    static hasMany = [evaluations:Evaluation]
}
```

**Evaluation**:

```
class Evaluation {

    UUID id
    Integer attemptNumber
    Date completenessDate
    Integer maxAttempt
    String testName
    Float testScore

    // Relations
    static belongsTo = [user:User]
}
```

And I have the following code to load the initial data. It is the same code for all three environments. Dev works well but prod and test show an error.

```
// Role
def adminRole = new SecRole(authority: 'ROLE_ADMIN')
def userRole = new SecRole(authority: 'ROLE_USER')

// Administrator
def newAdmin = new SecUser( 
     username: 'admin',
     password: 'admin',
     email: 'admin@example.com')

// Department
def idDepartment = new Department(name: 'I+D')

// Normal user
def newUser = new User(
     username: 'user',
     password: 'user',
     email: 'user@example.com',
     name: 'userTest',
     department: idDepartment
 )

// Evaluation
def evalUser = new Evaluation(
     testName: 'Test example',
     attemptNumber: 1,
     maxAttempt: 2,
     completenessDate: new Date(),
     testScore: 7.55,
     user: newUser)

// Saving roles
adminRole.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
userRole.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)

// Saving new admin
newAdmin.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)

// Saving departments
idDepartment.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)

// Saving new users
newUser.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)

// Assign user to role
if (!newAdmin.authorities.contains(adminRole)) {
    SecUserSecRole.create newAdmin, adminRole, true
}
if (!newUser.authorities.contains(userRole)) {
    SecUserSecRole.create newUser, userRole, true
}

// Saving evaluations - HERE IS THE ERROR
evalUserSTT1.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
```

And the error that is displayed only in test and prod environments is the following. I don't know why dev environment doesn't fail and the other environments fails with this violation.

[image: **Error**]

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact that in development environment, the datasource config is set to dbCreate = "create-drop" meaning every time you restart the application it drops and then re-creates the database. However in test and production environments are set to dbCreate = "update" where it only updates new changes. Now based on your bootstrap code, you are not checking if an object exists before save hence the bootstrap code will try to create the same roles and users that already exist from first run which causes conflicts.

In summary, modify your bootstrap code to check if records already exist, this is just an example, but will have to do the same for other roles and users etc, e.g.:

```
def adminRole
def adminRoleExists = SecRole.findByAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')
if(!adminRoleExists ) {
    adminRole = new SecRole(authority: 'ROLE_ADMIN')
    adminRole.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
}
```

Comment: Yes, I check it but I didn't type all my boostrap code because it is large. The problem is in user-evaluation relation. Besides, I also checked deleting all tables in production. Of this way, the data should be created.